# Elementary vanished after recent Windows Update

Tags: boot, system, release-odin

My first post.

I had Elementary os6, dual booting on my laptop with Windows 10.

All was great until a Windows 10 update. Now when I switch on my laptop, it just boots up into Windows, there is no option screen (Elementary or Windows).

What can I do to fix this?  Thanks

---

Thanks the cmd command ran, but on reboot no option to boot into elementary os.

I couldn't find a disk utility on my elementary USB disk.

I reinstalled elementary again, but over Windows so I have buggered up.

Does updating windows often corrupt elementary? Should I have dedicated computers rather than dual boot?

Answer (score 0):

So long as the update has not completely removed your Elementary partitions, you may be able to restore the boot menu like this:

1. Boot into Windows (if you're not already there)
2. Open "Command Prompt" as administrator
3. Update the boot controller with this:

   ```
   bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
   ```
4. Reboot

If you're not sure whether the Linux partitions still exist, you can look for them in the Disk Management tool, or by booting with an Elementary Live USB stick and using the Disks utility.

Comment: Matigo, I had been debating about having a dedicated elementary machine over a dual boot, circumstances have made the choice for me! Its an elementary device, with an encrypted drive.